# Binary sentiment classifer threshold

Tags: python, nlp, classification, sentiment-analysis, threshold

I have this code where I am trying to set a threshold that filters out neutral sentiment tweets from the test set and only classifies positive and negative  tweets. However, it is classifying only as positive (no negative predictions at all. The code is below, I wonder why it is only classifying as positive? Please help!

```
L_probs = linear.predict_proba(tweet_vectors_t1)

# Apply the threshold to classify the examples
pos_threshold = 0.99
neg_threshold = 0.4
neutral_threshold = [neg_threshold, pos_threshold] 

sentiments = []
for example_probs in L_probs:
    if max(example_probs) >= pos_threshold:
        sentiment = "positive"
    elif min(example_probs) < neg_threshold:
        sentiment = "negative"
    else:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    sentiments.append(sentiment)

filtered_tweet_vectors_t1 = [tweet_vectors_t1[i]
                             for i, sentiment in enumerate(sentiments)
                             if sentiment != "neutral"]
filtered_sentiments = [tweet_sentiment_t1[i]
                       for i, sentiment in enumerate(sentiments)
                       if sentiment != "neutral"]
filtered_sentiments = np.array(filtered_sentiments).astype(int)
filtered = linear.predict(filtered_tweet_vectors_t1)

accuracy = accuracy_score(filtered_sentiments, filtered)
precision = precision_score(filtered_sentiments, filtered)
recall = recall_score(filtered_sentiments, filtered)
f1 = f1_score(filtered_sentiments, filtered, average='macro')

print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
print('Precision:', precision)
print('Recall:', recall)
print('F1-score:', f1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(filtered_sentiments, filtered)
print (cm)
```

I have already tried altering the threshold values but not seeing any change yet

Comment: What is tweet_vectors_t1? Can you include it (or a subset of it) in your question?

Comment: tweet vectors t1 is the vectors in the test set

Comment: Binary classification should have labels 1.0 and -1.0, not 1.0 and 0.0

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the way you are using the logic.

Try the below and see if you are running into any issues, hopefully that fixes your code. If not, let me know

```
sentiments = []
for example_probs in L_probs:
    neg_prob, pos_prob = example_probs
    if pos_prob >= pos_threshold:
        sentiment = "positive"
    elif neg_prob >= neg_threshold:
        sentiment = "negative"
    else:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    sentiments.append(sentiment)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. so much for your answer. Unfortuntely I am still running into the issue of everything being classified as positive.
Accuracy: 0.4163126593033135
Precision: 0.4163126593033135
Recall: 1.0
F1-score: 0.2939412117576485
[[   0 2061]
 [   0 1470]]

This is the output of the confusion matrix and metrics,  if that helps.

Comment: Is your dataset imbalanced ? It could be possbily from imbalanced datasets. Check using print(" distribution:")
print(pd.Series(tweet_sentiment_t1).value_counts())

Comment: No it is not, I balanced it before I trained

Comment: Try to adjust the threshold then. Since you're using fixed threshold values for positive and negative classification, consider adjusting these values to see if it helps in getting both positive and negative predictions. You can experiment with different values for pos_threshold and neg_threshold to find the optimal balance.